# Why HDMI costs more energy?

Tags: hdmi

I just bought a 32" LED, and tried to test the HDMI using my laptop Dell XPS 15, but because where i live, we suffer from having sometimes low voltage, i have noticed that each time  it happens, i lost the signal! and everything go black and then back after 1 second!

Does this happens or the TV has problems?

Comment: That doesn't mean it uses more energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a power issue. For a TV, the amount of power taken to show a picture on the screen is much larger than any of the input signals.

It's far more likely that you have an issue with the configuration in your laptop. Is HDMI output on?

Comment: yes, it seems that it is the problem of the model, here i dont even have to activate the hdmi, i have no option to the external device, i must update the driver!
thank you!